# How to insert text in a td with id, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I know it may be a simple thing, but I can't figure out. I am trying to insert some text coming from a JavaScript function onload event into a td.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function insertText ()
   {
       //function to insert any text on the td with id "td1"
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="javascript:insertText()">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td id="td1">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Any help?

Comment: Make sure that the second <body> tag is actually </body>, and the same with the closing </script> tag. Maybe that's just a typo when you put it into the question, but you never know.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertText () {
    document.getElementById('td1').innerHTML = "Some text to enter";
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="insertText();">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="td1"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to note that ie <= 9 don't let you do innerHTML for table elements

Comment: @Denis do you have a cite for that? This was done for a table cell `<td>` element not a whole table or table body element.

Comment: Well, I admit my mistake, innerHTML to td really works in ie9, but all other elements of the table are read-only http://stackoverflow.com/a/4729743/1221082

Comment: take care of content to avoid XSS

Answer (score 35):

append a text node as follows

```
var td1 = document.getElementById('td1');
var text = document.createTextNode("some text");
td1.appendChild(text);
```

Comment: The important feature of this solution is that it does not destroy the current contents of the parent element.

Answer (score 17):

There are several options... assuming you found your TD by `var td = document.getElementyById('myTD_ID');` you can do:

- `td.innerHTML = "mytext";`
- `td.textContent= "mytext";`
- `td.innerText= "mytext";`  - this one may not work outside IE? Not sure
- Use firstChild or children array as previous poster noted.

If it's just the text that needs to be changed, textContent is faster and less prone to XSS attacks (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

Comment: For some reason I get Object doesnt support this property or method.
But thanks anyway.

Comment: Any that are preceded by getElement -> y <- ById.

Answer (score 4):

If your `<td>` is not empty, one popular trick is to insert a non breaking space `&nbsp;` in it, such that:

```
 <td id="td1">&nbsp;</td>
```

Then you will be able to use:

```
 document.getElementById('td1').firstChild.data = 'New Value';
```

Otherwise, if you do not fancy adding the meaningless `&nbsp` you can use the solution that Jonathan Fingland described in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163558/how-to-insert-text-in-a-td-with-id-using-javascript/2163613#2163613).

Answer (score 3):

**Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)**

Look how easy it would be if you did.

**Example:**

```
$('#td1').html('hello world');
```

Comment: old post, but still: you should never use jquery for those very easy things. it´s not even less code with jquery.

Comment: @luschn what if their site already uses JQuery heavily and its already loaded. Your statement is very broad. Never?

Comment: yes, never ;) - even if the site already uses jquery, you should aim for using vanilla js, because it is faster. and maybe you want to remove the jquery dependency sooner or later.

Comment: @luschn one of jquery's aim is to remove cross browser issues. Depending on the application of jquery/js the performance difference is moot.

Comment: there are no real issues with cross browser issues anymore. you should not support IE8 ;) - anyway, for the very simple task of adding some text to a html tag, it is really pointless to use jquery imho. people don´t really learn javascript that way, they just learn how to use a tool that just takes more download time with the same amount of code ;) - just my opinion though :)

Comment: @luschn - you're in denial, there are still some cross browser problems even today. And considering this post what over 7+ years ago, you're late to game on this answer.

Comment: there are NO cross browser problems with setting html to a div with an id ;) - even 7+ years ago, this was already a bad idea and no problem at all for all browsers. but again, just my opinion.