# Replace leading spaces with &nbsp; in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text like the following, with embedded spaces that show indentation of some xml data:

```
&lt;Style id="KMLStyler"&gt;<br>
  &lt;IconStyle&gt;<br>
    &lt;colorMode&gt;normal&lt;/colorMode&gt;<br>
```

I need to use Javascript to replace each LEADING space with

```
&nbsp;
```

so that it looks like this:

```
&lt;Style id="KMLStyler"&gt;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;IconStyle&gt;<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;colorMode&gt;normal&lt;/colorMode&gt;<br>
```

I have tried a basic replace, but it is matching all spaces, not just the leading ones.  I want to leave all the spaces alone except the leading ones.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript does not have the convenient `\G` (not even look-behinds), so there's no pure regex-solution for this AFAIK. How about something like this:

```
function foo() {
  var leadingSpaces = arguments[0].length;
  var str = '';
  while(leadingSpaces > 0) {
    str += '&nbsp;';
    leadingSpaces--;
  }
  return str;
}

var s = "   A B C";
print(s.replace(/^[ \t]+/mg, foo));
```

which produces:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;A B C
```

Tested here: http://ideone.com/XzLCR

### EDIT

Or do it with a anonymous inner function (is it called that?) as commented by glebm in the comments:

```
var s = "   A B C";
print(s.replace(/^[ \t]+/gm, function(x){ return new Array(x.length + 1).join('&nbsp;') }));
```

See *that* in action here: http://ideone.com/3JU52

Comment: awesome!  I did have to add the "g" flag to get it to work with multiple lines separated by \n chars; it only seemed to be replacing the spaces on the very first line.  If you want to edit your post to add the g, I'll accept it!

Comment: @Kevin, ah, yes, I forgot the the `g` modifier.

Comment: `s.replace(/^\s*/mg, function(x) { return new Array(++x.length).join('&nbsp;') })`

Comment: @glebm, yeah, that looks neat. Note that the `*` should be replaced with a `+` and since `\s` also matches line breaks, I opted to use `[ \t]` instead (although a line break wouldn't be matched, of course. Just for clarity.).

Comment: I like the [ \t] b/c I did NOT want line breaks matched.  I also like that it's not an anonymous function since this code will get called a lot and I don't want the anonymous function to have to be created each time, since it is exactly the same, and I'm not sure about how smart JS engines are about noticing that it's the same function and just caching it.

Comment: `'\u00A0'` instead of `'&nbsp;'` means you can insert as [text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2163649/673991) instead of html, a safer practice with untrusted input.

Answer (score 1):

Use `^` to anchor your pattern at the beginning of the string, or if you'r dealing with a multiline string (ie: embedded newlines) add `\n` to your pattern. You will need to match the whole set of leading spaces at once, and then in the replacement check the length of what was matched to figure out how many nbsps to insert.