# Mysterious runtime error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, runtime-error

IE version : 8.0.6001.18702

```
<tr id="week-days"></tr>

function displayWeekDay( lang )
{
    var txt = '<td>num</td>';
    for ( i = 0; i < langs[lang].day.length; i++ )
        if ( i == 5 )       txt += '<td class="red"><b>'   + langs[lang].day[i] + '</b></td>';
        else if ( i == 6 )  txt += '<td class="red"><b>'   + langs[lang].day[i] + '</b></td>';
        else                txt += '<td><b>'               + langs[lang].day[i] + '</b></td>';
    document.getElementById("week-days").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

The error is in the last line - document.getElementById("week-days").innerHTML = txt;

I`m a little bit confused - there is an error, but everything is displaying properly. There is no error on Mozilla, Chrome, Safari. Any idea will apreciated.

edit
[image]

Comment: Are you running the script before the tr exists?

Comment: **Unknown runtime error**. That is probably the most descriptive error message I have ever seen. q_q

Comment: can you throw this into a jsFiddle or similar for us to mess around with?

Comment: No the tr exist in the html and isn`t dinamically generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN: "the innerText and innerHTML properties of the table and tr objects are read-only" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998(v=vs.85).aspx

Solution is to create a tr element with the dom, or to build a full temporary table using html, then move the row to the destination table. Like the following:

```
/** Appends a row to the given tbody */
function appendRow(tbody, trHTML) {
  var tempNode = document.createElement('div');
  tempNode.innerHTML = "<table><tr>" + trHTML + "</tr></table>";
  var tempTable = tempNode.firstChild;
  tbody.appendChild(tempTable.rows[0] );
}
```

You could modify the function to specify the location to insert to, or another tr to insert before or after.

See [Can't set innerHTML on tbody in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729644/cant-innerhtml-on-tbody-in-ie/4729874)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an IE issue that has existed for [quite some time](http://ajaxian.com/archives/innerhtml-gotchas). I've ran into it myself in the past.  You might want to try creating the nodes via DOM methods.