# Cannot read property 'getComputedStyle' of undefined ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I use ckeditor on my website, and from time to time when I load my page I get this error which blocks the ckeditor:

```
"Cannot read property 'getComputedStyle' of undefined ckeditor"
```

Here's the code that initializes the ckeditor :

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('TA_comments', {
     toolbar: 'MyToolbar_user',
     on: {
         'instanceReady': function (evt) {
             //Set the focus to your editor
             CKEDITOR.instances.TA_comments.focus();
         }
     }
 });
```

Any idea where it can come because it's really a random problem on all browsers?

Thanks !

Comment: Any chance for a stack trace of this error?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error and it was caused by calling $('#id').empty(); 
Followed the ideas in this post:

[How do I clear the contents of a div without innerHTML = "";](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057759/how-do-i-clear-the-contents-of-a-div-without-innerhtml)

and used this code:

```
var node = document.getElementById('id');
 while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was a  problem with a jquery plugin mscustomscrollbar. 
To resolve this I deleted the plugin and used css3 to style scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem. My solution was: Client was using adblock pro, and I found out that in adblock our page that is using ckeditor is blocked! Removed our page from adbblock and it works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue. I put a delay on the `.replace()` and it's working fine now. As this is not a good solution I Know but I didn't find the exact cause and also it's generating randomly so finally I put a `setTimeout()` and the problem has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

As per [this issue](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor/issues/191) using [divarea plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/divarea) will solve this by replacing iframe used in editable area with a div