# javascript runtime error save/restore

Tags: javascript, html, css, runtime-error

I have created this code its make to store a table in a variable when i press save and return back to that state when i press restore but i seem to come across a runtime error on the last code (the Id of the table is sudoku) it works in firefox but not IE, Thanks

```
var clone
function save()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("sudoku")
    clone = table.innerHTML
}

function restore()
{
    document.getElementById("sudoku").innerHTML=clone
}
```

**Edit**:
Error Message:

```
Webpage error details User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; CPNTDF; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; BOIE9;ENUS) Timestamp: Mon, 15 Oct 2012 16:57:44 UTC Message: Unknown runtime error Line: 50 Char: 128 Code: 0 URI: file:///F:/uni%20work/home/Second%20year/CO525/assessments/Assessment2/assessmen‌​t2/javascript.js Message: Unknown runtime error Line: 50 Char: 128 Code: 0 URI: file:///F:/uni%20work/home/Second%20year/CO525/assessments/Assessment2/assessmen‌​t2/javascript.js
```

**edit**
full code:

```
    var current_cell = null; // the currently selected cell
    var saved = {};     // Object for saving the current game
    function initialize() {
var col, row;
// Work through all the cells in the table and set
// onclick event handlers and classNames for the empty
// ones.
for (row = 0; row <=8; row++) {
    for (col=0; col <= 8; col++) {
        var cell = document.getElementById('cell_' + col + '_' + row);
        if (!parseInt(cell.innerHTML)) {
            // cell is empty
            cell.onclick = selectCell;
            cell.className = 'tofill';
        }
    }
}
document.onkeypress = keyPress;
save();
    }
    var current_cell = null; // the currently selected cell
    var saved = {};     // Object for saving the current game
    function initialize() {
var col, row;
// Work through all the cells in the table and set
// onclick event handlers and classNames for the empty
// ones.
for (row = 0; row <=8; row++) {
    for (col=0; col <= 8; col++) {
        var cell = document.getElementById('cell_' + col + '_' + row);
        if (!parseInt(cell.innerHTML)) {
            // cell is empty
            cell.onclick = selectCell;
            cell.className = 'tofill';
        }
    }
}
document.onkeypress = keyPress;
save();
    }

    // mouse button event handler
    function selectCell() {
if (current_cell !== null) {
    current_cell.className = 'tofill';
}
current_cell = this;
current_cell.className = 'selected';
    }

    // Capture keyboard key presses. If the key pressed is a digit
    // then add it to the current cell. If it is a space then empty
    // the current cell.
    function keyPress(evt) {
if (current_cell == null)
    return;
var key;
if (evt)
    // firefox or chrome
    key = String.fromCharCode(evt.charCode);
else
    // IE
    key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
if (key == ' ')
    current_cell.innerHTML = '';
else if (key >= '1' && key <= '9')
    current_cell.innerHTML = key;
    }

    var clone
    function save()
    {
    var table = document.getElementById("sudoku");
    clone = table.innerHTML;
    }

   function restore()
    {
    document.getElementById("sudoku").innerHTML=clone;
   }
```

Comment: post the full code.. and the error message..

Comment: Please give the actual error message

Comment: sorry first time using this, the whole code is too much to post is there another way?

Comment: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; CPNTDF; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; BOIE9;ENUS)
Timestamp: Mon, 15 Oct 2012 16:57:44 UTC


Message: Unknown runtime error
Line: 50
Char: 128
Code: 0
URI: file:///F:/uni%20work/home/Second%20year/CO525/assessments/Assessment2/assessment2/javascript.js


Message: Unknown runtime error
Line: 50
Char: 128
Code: 0
URI: file:///F:/uni%20work/home/Second%20year/CO525/assessments/Assessment2/assessment2/javascript.js

Comment: First guess:  The contents of `clone` are getting trashed.

Comment: line 50 is document.getElementById("sudoku").innerHTML=clone  btw

Comment: it works on firefox but not IE thats what is bugging me

Comment: Fact: Anything above an alert will take some debugging in IE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DOM inbuilt javascript method `cloneNode` to clone your node..

E.G.

```
 var clone;
    function save()
    {
        var table = document.getElementById("sudoku");
        clone = table.cloneNode(true);
    }

    function restore()
    {
        document.getElementById("sudoku").parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }
```

FOR Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.cloneNode

Comment: im afraid that makes a copy instead of removing the first one and replacing it with the previous @Ashirvad

Comment: it creates exact copy of node.for easy explanation  visit http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_node_clonenode.asp

Comment: yes , but the copy is created underneath the old table so as a result there is two tables on the browser instead of one

Comment: then you can just clear the first one like this add this line in restore function  document.getElementById("sudoku").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("sudoku"));

Answer (score 1):

I assume `#sudoku` is a `<table>` element, isn't it? [Internet Explorer does not allow setting the `innerHTML` property on table elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4729644/1048572).

Instead, use proper DOM methods or just don't try to store HTML strings, but the contents of your sudoku in a two-dimensional array.

Comment: yes, its the ID for a table.. i see, is there any other way around this then?

Comment: The linked question has some answers; apart from that I only can recommend not to use `innerHTML`

Comment: I suspected as much I just didn't want to go through the trouble of creating an array

Answer (score 0):

This is a long standing problem with IE and inserting new HTML using the `innerHTML` attribute.
(Gee, who'd have guessed, a problem with IE!!)

If you're willing to go to jQuery, then you can do it using...

```
$("#mytable").html(myHtml);
```

Otherwise it should work if you can somehow place the html into the `innerHTML` attribute of a `<div>` tag.

Another option is to create the individual objects yourself using the `document.createElement("TR");` style of coding.

Comment: Fair enough @Jimmy, was just giving you another choice should you have that option

Comment: would i just have to replace the entire code with $("#mytable").html(myHtml); ?

Comment: No @Jimmy, not the entire code... that command is purely for setting the inner html of the selected object, so in your case it would be replacing the `document.getElementById("sudoku").innerHTML=clone` line with `$("#sudoku").html(clone);`

Answer (score -1):

The code added by you look like fine but I think you are missing semicolon after each statements.

```
    var clone;
    function save()
    {
        var table = document.getElementById("sudoku");
        clone = table.innerHTML;
    }

    function restore()
    {
        document.getElementById("sudoku").innerHTML=clone;
    }
```

Also you can go through jQuery html method. Click here [jQuery html() funciton](http://mycodeprograms.blogspot.com/2012/10/jquery-html-method.html), if you want to read more about html() function.

e.g

```
    `$('#sudoku').html(clone);`
```

Comment: Javascript does not require semi-colons at the end of every statement (unlike C/C++/C#/etc), so this would have no effect on the current issue