# java script unable to find the element

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, google-chrome

here is my issue:

when i say getelementbyid("table1") it says"**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null**"

i am rendering a dynamic table via java script asshown below:

```
function mainProcessing()
{
        <% ProductController pc=new ProductController();%>

        var val = <%=pc.doTask()%>
        var jobj=JSON.stringify(val);
        document.write(jobj);
        alert(jobj);

         var obj=JSON.parse(jobj);
        alert("jobj");
        alert(obj.toString());
        var object = eval("(" + jobj+ ")");

        alert("this part is done");
        return object;
}
function drawtable()
{
    var JSONObj=mainProcessing();
    var tablecontents = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
   {
      tablecontents += "<tr>";
      tablecontents += "<td>" + i + "</td>";
      tablecontents += "<td>" + i * 100 + "</td>";
      tablecontents += "<td>" + i * 1000 + "</td>";
      tablecontents += "</tr>";
   }

 document.write(JSONObj.toString());       
    alert("just outside nested loop");
   document.getElementById("table1").innerHTML = tablecontents;
}
```

for testing i have inserted randome values in the table.

and that html part goes like this:

```
<title>Indian Divine !!!</title>
</head>
<body onload="drawtable()">
<center>
<h1>my name is jobj</h1>
    <table id="table1">

    </table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

the browser user is Chrome.
IDE Eclips Juno

Comment: Your HTML is missing some opening tags.

Comment: that is fine i have just copied and pasted the relevant part of code... @Uooo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) after the page load. It replaces the content. If you are trying to see what is in it, use `console.log(jobj);`

Second, if you plan on using this code with IE, [you can't set the tables innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729644/cant-innerhtml-on-tbody-in-ie).

Third, do not use `eval()` to convert JSON. Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: i am a basic programmer....
and i will keep all these point sin my ming from now ...
these are dam helpful ...

Answer (score 2):

`document.write(mayur)` replaces the whole document (including the table) with the value of `mayur`, because you are calling it after the document was loaded. At the moment you are trying to access the element with ID `table1`, it does not exist anymore.

Solution: Don't use `document.write`.

More info: [MDN - document.wite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)