# cloning / duplicating html nodes including their styles

Tags: javascript, html

I recently started working on cloning display objects.

I have observed there are basically two ways of cloning nodes:

1) I have tried cloning nodes with "cloneNode" method, which is pretty good but is not supported in old browsers.

```
var newNode = oldNode.cloneNode(deep);
```

[cloneNode Reference MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)

2) For older browsers I am trying to copy outerHTML and set the value to the the innerHTML. Like

```
newNode.innerHTML = oldNode.outerHTML
```

**NOTE:**

**For some old versions of internet explorer, innerHTML is a read-only property for table elements.**

What is the best of the above methods or is there any other best method. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried jquery's `$.clone` method? http://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
$( "#oldNode" ).clone().appendTo( "#newNode" );
```

EDIT: ahh I see your problem is innerHtml is read only in ie tables

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729644/cant-innerhtml-on-tbody-in-ie) provides a workaround for innerHtml in an ie table row

```
function setTBodyInnerHTML(tbody, html) {
  var temp = tbody.ownerDocument.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = '<table>' + html + '</table>';

  tbody.parentNode.replaceChild(temp.firstChild.firstChild, tbody);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: this is trickyer than I thought, updated my answer to two things to try if you haven't already

Comment: I tried jQuery clone method, its good but I am looking for pure javascript solution.