# IE8 and getElementById doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I already read some posts about IE8 causing trouble with getElementByID but couldn't find a workaround. My code looks like this right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  function settext(id) {
  switch(id) {
            case "0": document.getElementById('text').innerHTML="something";
            break;
            case "1": document.getElementById('text').innerHTML="again something";
            break;
            default: document.getElementById('text').innerHTML="something the third";
            break;
            }
   }
//]]>
</script><select style="width: 145px" onchange="settext(this.value)">
<option value="-1">something</option>
<option value="0">again</option>
<option value="1">and so on</option>
</select>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="text"></table>
```

It works fine with Firefox, Chrome and IE10.
I'd be glad to get some help with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please define doesn't work well :)

Comment: There are issues with `getElementById` in IE8 ???

Comment: I see nothing with an ID of "text".

Comment: As it stands this question cannot be answered. Please add the element with ID text to your code, in addition to the select menu, so users can help you.

Comment: The ID of "text" is in a following table.

Comment: See my complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On IE8 **this.value** is an issue but not *getElementById* . I think you are setting the innerHTML to a non text node.

Try this - it works for a text node.

**UPDATE**: You can't set value to a table's innerHTML, you should access to child cells or rows and change them like that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function settext(id) {
switch(id) {
            case "0":document.getElementById('text').rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML="something";
            break;
            case "1": document.getElementById('text').rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML="again something";
            break;
            default: document.getElementById('text').rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML="something the third";
            break;
            }
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select style="width: 145px" onchange="settext(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option value="-1">something</option>
<option value="0">again</option>
<option value="1">and so on</option>
</select>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="text"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Related answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4729743/1960455

Comment: Sadly it didn't help.

Comment: when you say document.getElementById('text'), where is the element in your page with id "text" ?

Comment: gotcha, You can't set value to a table's innerHTML, you should access to child cells or rows and change them like that :

Comment: You might want to reference the the answer to [can't innerHTML on tbody in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4729743/1960455)

Comment: Yes! Thank you. That was my stupid mistake! It works perfect now. Thank you a lot for your time.