# how can i show data in table received from Database through ajax in php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is the `table` I want to show data in `td` through id.

```
<tbody>
<td id="show_file"></td>
</tbody>
```

And This is the function which sends a request to `EditDeleteLecture.php` to retrieve data from the database.

```
function readRecords(){
    var readrecords = "readrecords";
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax/EditDeleteLecture.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{readrecords:readrecords},
        success:function(data,status){
            var user1 = JSON.parse(data);           
            $("#show_file").val(user1.file_name);
        }
    });
}
```

And this code is written in the `EditDeleteLecture.php`.

```
if(isset($_POST['readrecords'])){
    $displayquery = "select content.file_name,content.cont_id AS ID,
                            content.description,content.course_code,
                            content.upload_date,course.course_name 
                    from content 
                        join class on class.course_code=content.course_code 
                        join course on class.course_code=course.course_code 
                        join faculty on faculty.faculty_name=class.faculty_name 
                    where faculty.faculty_phone='$single_user' 
                    order by ID desc"; 

    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$displayquery);
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {            
        $response1 = $row;
    } 
    echo json_encode($response1);
}
```

console.log(data) shows

```
this.{"0":"waqsa.pdf",
    "file_name":"waqsa.pdf",
    "1":1193,
    "ID":1193,
    "2":"aaaa",
    "description":"aaaa",
    "3":"CS-311",
    "course_code":"CS-311",
    "4":"2018-10-22",
    "upload_date":"2018-10-22",
    "5":"Programming Fundamental",
    "course_name":"Programming Fundamental"
}
```

Comment: What is is working here? [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: Where is `$single_user` defined?

Comment: $single_user is the name of SESSION variable.

Comment: What session variable? Please include all relevant code in your question.  Also explain in detail exactly what the difference is between the current result/behavior and the desired result/behavior.  Are you getting errors?  Have you checked for errors?

Comment: No, It don't gives errors. the echo json_encode($response1); returns data. but I don't know how to display data in the table.

Comment: And the session is assigned to $single_user. here is the code $single_user=$_SESSION['FT_id'];

Comment: So your PHP is working correctly and this is just a Javascript question?

Comment: To load something into a `<td>` Examples here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163558/how-to-insert-text-in-a-td-with-id-using-javascript _HINT_ You dont use `.val()` as `<td>`'s dont have a value attribute

Comment: yes. PHP works correctly

Comment: I doubt php is working correctly, you're overwritting the result when looping the rows

Comment: Would you show us the result of `console.log(data);` in `success` ? `$.each(data ...` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Cid console.log(data) shows this.{"0":"waqsa.pdf","file_name":"waqsa.pdf","1":1193,"ID":1193,"2":"aaaa","description":"aaaa","3":"CS-311","course_code":"CS-311","4":"2018-10-22","upload_date":"2018-10-22","5":"Programming Fundamental","course_name":"Programming Fundamental"}

Comment: John. Feel free to edit your question with extra information like that. Nobody can read stuff like that in a comment

Comment: Also use `sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)` then you will only get ONE version of the columns i.e. not the numerically indexed bits

Comment: [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) may be what you are looking for

Comment: @RiggsFolly  SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC gives an error "call to undefined function"

Comment: Thats very odd You did out it like this right? `while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {`

Comment: @Cid thanks my problem solved by writing text(). thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. Give a try to more searches before asking, this is how you can progress.

Comment: @Cid but it doesn't shows the date.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. the problem is solved. i have just wite  `$("#show_file").text(user1.file_name);`
instead of

```
$("#show_file").text(user1.file_name);
```

Comment: But it says the same thing???